# Error of LSTM expecting certain dimensions while passing array

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have been trying to reuse the idea from [here](https://github.com/rafadaguiar/myo/blob/master/myo.py) on my data. However, I am having trouble with the error:

"ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_16_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 4)"

What I am trying to run:

```
def main():
    #X, Y = load_data()
    X, Y = load_file()
    print("------")    
    print(X)
    print(X.shape)
    print(type(X))
    print("------")
    print(Y)
    print(Y.shape)
    print(type(Y))
    print("------")

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)

    model = build_model(150, 100)

    # Error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_16_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (8, 4)
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=200, batch_size=100, verbose=2)
```

Where I define the model:

```
def build_model(first_layer_neurons, second_layer_neurons):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(first_layer_neurons, input_dim=NUMBER_OF_FEATURES, dropout_U=0.3))
    model.add(Dense(second_layer_neurons))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    # model.add(Flatten()) What I tried
    model.add(Dense(NUMBER_OF_CLASSES, activation="softmax"))
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
                  optimizer="adam",
                  metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model
```

My data is of the type and shape:

[image]

If needed, I am using:

```
NUMBER_OF_FEATURES = 5
NUMBER_OF_TIME_STEPS = 50
NUMBER_OF_CLASSES = 4
TEMP_DIR = "temp/"
SEED = 7
```

I tried to add flatten() on my model but that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

LSTM takes input of the shape `(n_samples, n_timesteps, n_features)`. You should reshape your data into this format. For example, if your raw input data is of shape `(1000, 5)`, you can split it into 10 samples each with 100 time steps and thus get an input of shape `(10, 100, 5)`. You can have overlapping sample too.

Same reshaping should happen to output too. So if the original output shape is `(1000, 1)`, you should reshape it to `(10, 100, 1)`.

Note that the n_timsteps is a hyperparameter you should decide using insight about your data or just by hyperparameter tuning.